# How to search for an item in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

How can I do something like this.

```
index=[[test1,test2,test3],[test4,test5,test6],[test7,test8,test9]]
if test5 is in index:
    print True
```

Comment: Is 2 the max nesting level?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [any](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) + [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html?highlight=generator%20expression#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions):

```
if any(test5 in subindex for subindex in index):
    print True
```

Comment: maybe even `print any(test5 in subindex for subindex in index)` :)

Comment: @RomanPekar, I didn't do that, because OP's code does not have `else: print False`. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Loop over your list of lists, and check for existence in each inner list:

```
for list in list_of_lists:
  if needle in list :
    print 'Found'
```

Comment: @falsetru's solution is definitely cleaner and more pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

try by this way

```
index = [['test1','test2','test3'], ['test4','test5','test6'], ['test7','test8','test9']]
any(filter(lambda x : 'test5' in x, index))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps try itertools to unroll the array :-

```
index=[[test1,test2,test3],[test4,test5,test6],[test7,test8,test9]]
if test5 in itertools.chain(*index):
    print True
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
index=[[test1,test2,test3],[test4,test5,test6],[test7,test8,test9]]
flat_index=[item for sublist in index for item in sublist]
if test5 is in flat_index:
    print True
```

see also [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: this is... exactly the same as my answer?